# Unset header in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, rewrite

I have a file located at `http://mysite.loc/js/index.php/x.js`
and in .htaccess I want to write a rule that unsets a header in the request to `/js/index.php/x.js` I wrote this, but it didn't work. Where is my mistake?

```
<filesMatch "/js/index.php/x.js">
    Header unset X-Content-Type-Options
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: Are you sure the filesMatch matches your path? Remember that it is a regular expression match.

Comment: That doesn't look like a filesystem path (unless "index.php" is a directory?). That looks like a URL-path, which won't be matched by a Files/FilesMatch container.